# How do I get ui from a widget in order to connect it in another class?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to connect a QPushButton (startListeningPushButton) from my StartWindow to a slot in my MainController. I still have a few questions:

1. Should I make a pointer of `Ui::startWidget ui`, because by default Qt created it as a normal variable?
2. Is `getStartWindow()` the right way to get the `StartWindow` from `ViewController`?
3. What would be the right way to get `startListeningPushButton` from `StartWindow` (is my getter right)?

This is my code:

**MainController.cpp:**

```
MainController::MainController()
{
    connect(m_viewController.getStartWindow()->getStartListeningPushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainController::bla)

}
```

**ViewController.cpp:**

```
StartWindow* ViewController::getStartWindow()
{
    return &startWindow;
}
```

**StartWindow.cpp:**

```
QPushButton* StartWindow::getStartListeningPushButton()
{
    return ui->fStartListeningPushButton;
}
```

**StartWindow.h:**

```
#ifndef STARTWINDOW_H
#define STARTWINDOW_H

#include "ui_startwindow.h"

class StartWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    StartWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~StartWindow();
    QPushButton* getStartListeningPushButton();

private:
    Ui::startWidget *ui;
};

#endif // STARTWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using Qt Designer and Qt IDE generated such code that it's object not a pointer I don't think that you should make it pointer.
2. Yeah, returning a pointer to QWidget (StartWindow in your case) is pretty OK.
3. Your getter is OK.

Seems like you have mistype in your connect, it should look like this:

```
QObject::connect(m_viewController.getStartWindow()->getStartListeningPushButton(), SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 this, SLOT(bla()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you have and then what is your problem.

The only thing I doubt would work is the first parameter of your call to `connect`:

`m_viewController.getStartWindow()->getStartListeningPushButton` should actually be `m_viewController.getStartWindow()->getStartListeningPushButton()` (to have the function be called so that you get the pointer to expected `QPushButton` and pass it to the `connect` function).

In the [`connect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) function:

- First and third parameter must be of type `QObject*`. So this can either be `this` pointer (if current class is derived from `QObject`), or any class attribute of type `QObject*` (`ui->fStartListeningPushButton`) or a function call returning `QObject*` (`m_viewController.getStartWindow()->getStartListeningPushButton()`). But `m_viewController.getStartWindow()->getStartListeningPushButton` (with no `()`) does not make sense here).
- Second parameter must be a `signal` (declared in header file class using `signals:` keyword. You don't need implement any code here, you just declare the signal and Qt MOC mechanism implements it silently). Valid syntax for this parameter is `&QPushButton::clicked` or `SIGNAL(clicked())` (Qt4 syntax, still valid in Qt5).
- Fourth parameter must be a `slot` (declared in header file class using `slots:` keyword, and implemented by you). Valid syntax for this parameter is `&MainController::bla` or `SLOT(bla())` (Qt4 syntax, still valid in Qt5).
- There's actually a fifth optional parameter to use when you'll start dealing with threads.

Comment: I don't have problems yet, but I am not sure if my approach is right. Thats the reason I asked 3 things

Comment: Your approach is rigth, only you misunderstand the connect parameters. See edited answer for more details.